# Dask DataFrame.map_partition() to write to db table

Tags: python, mysql, dask, dask-distributed

I have a dask dataframe that contains some data after some transformations. I want to write those data back to a mysql table. I have implemented a function that takes a dataframe a db url and writes the dataframe back to database. Because I need some to make some final edits on the data of the dataframe, I use pandas `df.to_dict('record')` to handle the write.

the function looks like that

```
def store_partition_to_db(df, db_url):
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from mymodels import DBTableBaseModel

    records_dict = df.to_dict(records)
    records_to_db = []
    for record in records_dict:
        transformed_record = transform_record_some_how # transformed_record is a dictionary
        records_to_db.append(transformed_record)

    engine = create_engine(db_uri)
    engine.execute(DBTableBaseModel.__table__.insert(), records_to_db)

    return records_to_db
```

In my dask code:

```
from functools import partial
partial_store_partition_to_db(store_partition_to_db db_url=url)
dask_dataframe = dask_dataframe_data.map_partitions(partial_store_partition_to_db)
all_records = dask_dataframe.compute()

print len([record_dict for record_list in all_records for record_dict in record_list]] # Gives me 7700
```

But when I go to the respected table in MySQL I get 7702 with the same value on all columns that is 1. When I try to filter all_records with that value, no dictionary is returned.  Has anyone met this situation before? How do you handle db writes from paritions with dask?

PS: I use LocalCluster and dask distributed

Comment: Instead of `engine.execute`, have you tried pandas `to_sql` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't provide meta information in the `map_partition` method and because of that it created a ataframe with foo values which I turns were written in the db